# How to predict unlabeled test data using trained machine learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written a ML-based Intrusion prediction. In the learning process, I used training and test data both labeled to evaluate the accuracy and generate confusion matrixes. I came up with good accuracy and now I want to test it with new data( Unlabeled data). How do I do that?

Comment: How could you test without knowing the truth?

Comment: @Julien I just want the prediction of unknown data. Does not matter whether it is a false positive or not.

Comment: Then just predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so say you do test on unlabeled data and your algorithm predicts some X output. How can you check the accuracy, how can you check if this is correct or not? This is the only thing that matters in predictions, how your program works on data it has not seen before.

The short answer is, you can't. You need to split your data into:

1. Training 70%
2. Validation 10%
3. Test 20%

All of these should be labled and accuracy, confusion matrix, f measure and anything else should be computed on the labled test data that your program has not seen before. Your train on training data and every once in a while you check the performance on the validation data to see if it is doing well or if you need to do adjustments. In the very end you check on test data. This is supervised learning, you always need labeled data.